# How to import video js for angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, video.js

I try to build an angular2 application with video js player but i don't know how to call. I try on the example.compontent.html like  there is not work and try in example.component.ts like

```
var videojs=require('video.js');
var player = videojs('my-player');
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean you don't know how to call? What do you mean when you so it does not work? Can you add the `example.component.html` code as well please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 2+ is written in TypeScript, therefore you'll need TypeScript definitions for VideoJS to be able to use the library's API properly in Angular 2. To do so, install @types/videojs via npm:

`npm install @types/videojs`

Now you can import VideoJS using the `import` statement.
Also, take notice that writing pure-JS is still possible in TypeScript.

Anyway, what you're trying to achieve would probably not work because your component's template and logic are separated until bundling, unlike in VideoJS's example where the script is located inside of the HTML template.
Therefore you'll need to pass the element itself using `document.getElementById`.

```
videojs(document.getElementById('my-player'));
```

I suggest you to refer to [this example of a VideoJS Angular 2 component](http://embed.plnkr.co/DrXJoH02IJLEdkYFu8HE/).

Comment: Great answer, but it's probably better to use a `@ViewChild` rather than calling `getElementById` directly

Comment: @user184994 totally agreed. That's definitely more Angular-ish.

Comment: the plunkr seems to be broken now.

Answer (score 3):

Simple steps:
 1. `npm install --save video.js`
 2. `npm install --save-dev @types/video.js`

After installation just import like this. Now we can use interfaces too like this.

```
 import * as videojs from 'video.js'

 class VideoComponent {
     public videoJS = videojs.default
     private videoPlayer: videojs.VideoJsPlayer
     private options: videojs.VideoJsPlayerOptions

     someMethod() {
        this.videoJS('my-player', {
          controls: true,
          autoplay: true,
          preload: 'auto'
        });

      }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked. I've never seen `packagename.default` used like this before though. What's the reason we have to do this? Did they just not make a default export?